# Counting 5-digit numbers and sharing slip of papers.

Tags: combinatorics

I've in my Combinatorics book the following exercise:

"We print one 5-digit number on a slip of paper. We include numbers beginning with 0's, for example 00158. Since digits 0,1, and 8 look the same upside down, and since 6 and 9 are interchanged when a slip of paper is turned upside down, 5-digit numbers such as 61891 and 16819 can share the same slip of paper. If we want to include all possible 5-digit numbers but allow for this kind of sharing, how many different slips of paper do we need?"

My line of thought is the following: If the number contain all 0,8,1,6 and 9 the can be turned upside down and the resulting number can share the same slip of paper, we have $$5^5$$ of such numbers. Some of them are identical to itself when turned upside down, in fact if the number is palindrome and is made only of 0,8 and 1 then when turned upside down the resulting number is the same. There are $$3^3$$ of those numbers. So at the end we will have $$5^5-3^3$$ numbers which can share the same slip of paper, in total we need $$10^5-5^5+3^3=96902$$ slips of papers.

Does it make any sense? Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to work with three types, type one is those that can't be flipped at all, like 2,3,4,5, and 7, type two is those that can be flipped and remain the same number, i.e. 1,8, and 0, and type three--6 and 9 which interchange when flipped. Any number using the first type requires it's own slip of paper. The trouble will come with the second and third types and how they will work both alone and with each other. Very interesting problem, thanks.

Comment: I just noticed in the original description, they say that 61891 turns into 16819, but they operation they talk about is turning 'upside down.' To me if you turn 61891 'upside down' you get 91861. However, this makes no sense if you write only on the front of the paper, so I guess they mean 'rotate by 180' degrees. An interesting extension to the problem would be to write on transparent slips and allow both flips and rotations.

Comment: As @Arby remarks it is a bit more precise to speak of a rotation. I also needed the context for getting the right understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers that can be turned upside down without changing have digits among $0,1,6,8,9$ (as you noted), are determined by their first three digits and do not have a $6$ or a $9$ as third digit. So there are $5\times5\times3=75$ of them.

So we find:

- $10^5-5^5$ slips are needed for the $10^5-5^5$ numbers that turned around are no numbers.
- $75$ slips are needed for the $75$ numbers that stay the same by turning around.
- $\frac12(5^5-75)$ slips are needed for the $5^5-75$ numbers that turned around are a number that differs from the original number.

So in total the number of slips of paper we need is:$$(10^5-5^5)+75+\frac12(5^5-75)=98475$$

Comment: Although I don't know, did you consider 06190 and 66199 doesn't change?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki after rotating 180 degrees both numbers have not changed.

Comment: I understood that 6 and 9 is correspond in opposite. I think you need this explanation, though.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: How did you count 06160, 09190 and 06190? I think you must say 0,1,8 are unchanged numbers, but 6 and 9 are converse numbers.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki 06160  changes by rotation. I need one slip for 06160 and its rotation 09190. The third bullet in my answer applies to both numbers. 06190 does not change. I need one slip for it. The second bullet applies to that. That there is a difference between on one hand $6$ and $9$ and on the other $0,1,8$ comes forward by the statement that $6$ and $9$ cannot be the third digit of a number that can rotated without changing. I don't think that needs a further explanation.

Comment: Well, the first sentence of your answer is wrong obviously, because you say 0,1,6,8,9 is unchanged, but 6,9 can be changed. -1.

Comment: No, he didn't say that. He said *5-digit numbers that don't change when you rotate them* have 0, 1 and 8 in the third position and 0,1,6,8 and 9 in the first and second positions. Take an example: if the first three digits are say 691--that will force the last two digits to be 69 giving 69169. Notice when you rotate it, you get 69169 again.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki I am not saving there that digit 6 is unchanged if it is rotated

Comment: The digit 6 changes to a 9, and also changes position and the overall effect is getting the same 5-digit number back.

Edit: Take 69169, the six in the first position changes to the 9 in the last position when rotated (and the 9 in the last position changes to 6 in the first), and the 9 in the second position changes to the 6 in the fourth position and vice versa. The overall effect is to get the same 5-digit number back. Therefore for number like that, you need one slip of paper--you **don't** get a new number by rotation.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Have you seen the comments of Arby? If not then I ask you to look at them now. One thing is certain for me: you downvoted an answer that is completely correct.